# AngularJS Resolve to wait until external images have loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A simple-ish question, I'm loading in images from an external site and I want to hold off my `resolve` until they have finished loading.

My `resolve` property for a particular view looks like this:

```
    resolve :{
      item: function($q, $route, $http, $timeout){

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        console.log("Params are " + $route.current.params.id);
        $http.get('/api/post/' + $route.current.params.id, { cache: true}).
          success(function(data) {
            if(data.post.length === 1){
              $http.get('/api/designerAlso/' + data.post[0].designer + '/' + data.post[0].gender, { cache: true})
              .success(function(results){
                data.post[0].sameDesigner = results.sameDesigner;
                successCb(data.post);
              });
            }else{
              successCb(data.post); 
            }
          });
          var successCb = function(result){
            if (angular.equals(result, [])){
              deferred.reject("Sorry, we couldn't find that item!");
            }else{
              deferred.resolve(result);
            }
          }

          return deferred.promise;
      }
    }
```

It brings in data from my database, which has a field called `imgs`, containing an array of URLs. Is it possible to resolve once the data from these URLs has finished loading, or am I kinda out of luck here?

Answer (score 3):

You can manually load the image(s) you want in a nested $http request inside the success function of resolve.item.  Simply resolve the promise in the success callback on image, and your view will not be rendered until the image has been loaded.

The downside of this is the browser will make another http request for the image once the view asks for it, but it will already been cached and ready to go.

```
resolve: {
   item: function () {
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       $http.get(*data call*).success(function (data) {
            $http.get(*image*).success(function () {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });
       });
       return deferred.promise;
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks mike. but how can call "data" into my controller?

Comment: dave - "data" is what is going to be returned by resolve.item. You may be confused by how the resolve property works in the angular router.  You can reference the properties set on the resolve object via dependency injection in your corresponding controller and you will have resolve.item available to you.

Comment: @mikeStone Hey Mike, what if I need a series of images to complete loading before resolving, so I can't attach the success callback onto the $http.get event.